# Libgdx IOS app with RoboVM crash because of okhttp

Tags: ios, libgdx, okhttp, grpc-java, robovm

I am trying to use Grpc in my libgdx app. Grpc uses okhttp to make network calls.
Its working perfectly fine in android, but when I am trying to port my libgdx app to ios using Robovm compiler, I am getting following crash:-

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE
at io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.<init>(StatusRuntimeException.java:58)
at io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException.<init>(StatusRuntimeException.java:50)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:259)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: We can not do TLS handshake on this Android version, please install the Google Play Services Dynamic Security Provider to use TLS
at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.configureTlsExtensions(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:302)
at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:96)
at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpProtocolNegotiator$AndroidNegotiator.negotiate(OkHttpProtocolNegotiator.java:218)
at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpTlsUpgrader.upgrade(OkHttpTlsUpgrader.java:63)
at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpClientTransport$4.run(OkHttpClientTransport.java:574)
```

Code-block:-

```
    public AuthenticateUserResponse authenticateUser(AuthenticateUserRequest request) {
      return io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(
          getChannel(), getAuthenticateUserMethod(), getCallOptions(), request);
    }
```

Gradle dependancies for Robovm & okhttp:-

```
roboVMVersion = '2.3.16'
gdxVersion = '1.10.0'
grpcVersion = '1.45.0'

api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:$grpcVersion"
```

Can someone help?

Comment: I am not sure if this a supported use-case? If this is running on iOS why does it invoke the AndroidNegotiator and generate a message saying "on this Android version" ?

Comment: So making it work on iOS (with TLS) will require work and investigation. If you really want this you may want to consider opening an issue on grpc-java repo.

Comment: I think its not supported officially. I thought someone might have workaround for this.